# usb_cam package as nodelet

Tags: robotic-arm, nodelet, camera, pandaboard, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

At the moment I use the usb_cam package from the bosch_drivers stack to acquire data from a webcam on an an ARM board. (I used the uvc_cam package also but the colors are weird).
Because the ARM board has limited computational resources I would like to ask if someone implemented the usb_cam package already as nodelet?

I saw the Tutorials about how to convert a node to nodlet package but my question is if somebody already did that. Would be great to get your help.

**EDIT:** I tried to port the usb_cam to the nodelet structure but without success (caused by lag of programming skills). Is there a better/more detailed tutorial than ["porting node to nodelet"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet/Tutorials/Porting%20nodes%20to%20nodelets)
?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50118/usb_cam-package-as-nodelet/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't appear that the package has a nodelet driver. Should you consider implementing one, here's a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet/Tutorials/Porting%20nodes%20to%20nodelets) on node-to-nodelet conversion to get you started

If you have code running on the ARM board which subscribes to the images and published by the driver, then yes, you are likely to receive a boost in framerate, *if* both the publisher and subscriber have nodelet implementations.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an outstanding nodelet pr https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam/pull/59

```
git clone -b feature/nodelet https://github.com/groove-x/usb_cam.git
```

I have tried it out and it looks to be working fine.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1